# How to do custom python imports?

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a way to have custom behaviour for import statements in Python? How? E.g.:

```
import "https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests"
import requests@2.11.1
import requests@7322a09379565bbeba9bb40000b41eab8856352e
```

Alternatively, in case this isn't possible... Can this be achieved in a standard way with function calls? How? E.g.:

```
import gitloader
repo = gitloader.repo("https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests")
requests = repo.from_commit("7322a09379565bbeba9bb40000b41eab8856352e")
```

There are two reasons for why I would like to do this. The first reason is convenience (Golang style imports). The second reason is that I need cryptographic verification of plugin modules for a project. I'm using Python 3.x

Comment: What's the problem with downloading the stuff and import it locally?

Comment: Also you wouldn't be able to "import" commits, that's not how git commits work.

Comment: I want/need to keep the filesystem read-only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're essentially asking is customization of the import steps. This was made possible with [PEP 302](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/) which brought about certain hooks for  for customization.

That PEP is currently not the source from which you should learn how importing works; rather, look at the [documentation for the `import` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) for reference. There [it states](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#finders-and-loaders):

> Python includes a number of default finders and importers. The first one knows how to locate built-in modules, and the second knows how to locate frozen modules. A third default finder searches an import path for modules. The import path is a list of locations that may name file system paths or zip files. *It can also be extended to search for any locatable resource, such as those identified by URLs.*
>
> *The import machinery is extensible, so new finders can be added to extend the range and scope of module searching*.

In short, you'll need to define the appropriate finder (to find the modules you're looking for) and an appropriate loader for loading these.